# can sites detect javascript executions on consoles?

Tags: javascript, web, bots

Im building a bot and im wondering whether if its even possible for sites to detect javascript executions on the console. For example for a certain site the bot needs to add the item to cart and I do this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('w_C8 w_DA w_DF')[0].click()
```

through the bot will sites be able to detect that it wasn't an actual human clicking or will they automatically now it was code run to click the button

Comment: since java script is the medium for site interactivity, instinct says no it will not be able to detect it.

Comment: *Can it* and *will it* are very different questions. Almost anything is possible. But not everything that is possible is actually done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they will be able to detect that, because click event contains more than just an information that it have been clicked, for example coordinates of a mouse pointer. You can check that yourself by defining onclick function, for example:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){console.log(e)};
document.body.click();
```

Now click and check the difference in console.

In onclick event object there is also a direct notification if it was actually clicked, or triggered:

```
e.isTrusted: false // clicked automatically
e.isTrusted: true // real click
```

Does anybody actually check that? Most sites surely don't.